# Quick way to add an or statement on a Jquery keydown function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, keyboard-shortcuts, keydown

Let's say I have a keydown element like so,

```
$.ctrl('13', function(){


)}
```

This will get ctrl + enter. However, I also want the code to run on command + enter on Mac. Is there a way, without changing much on the function, to have an or statement at the beginning of the function like so

```
$('.ctrl', '.metaKey')('13', function() {

)}
```

I imagine something like this being like ctrl or metakey + enter. Is there a way to do this in Jquery?

Comment: `$.ctrl()` is not core jQuery and is probably a plugin function. Need link to docs for that to be able to help. If it's a custom function in your code base would need to see the code for it

Answer (score 1):

I think you're thinking of `event.ctrlKey` which is whatever key you're listening for combined with the control key. You can access it like this:

```js
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.ctrlKey)
    alert("Ctrl + enter was pressed!!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click in this area to focus in this $(document) and press Ctrl+Enter
  <?p>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/ctrlKey
https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/